# Not sure how to parse this object with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, object

I am trying to parse the following object with `PHP`, but I have never encountered an object with `keys` like the one below

I need to get the `['users']` inside `_objectData:LazyJsonMapper\LazyJsonMapper:private` but when I do `$myobject->_objectData:LazyJsonMapper\LazyJsonMapper:private` it fails. How should I call it?

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated,
Thanks

```
API\Response\MediaLikersResponse Object
(
    [httpResponse] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
        (
            [reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => OK
            [statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 200
            [headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
                (
                    [Content-Type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => application/json
                        )

                )

            [headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
                (
                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                    [vary] => Vary
                    [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                    [pragma] => Pragma
                    [expires] => Expires
                    [content-language] => Content-Language
                    [date] => Date
                    [set-cookie] => Set-Cookie
                    [connection] => Connection
                    [x-encoded-content-encoding] => x-encoded-content-encoding
                    [x-encoded-content-length] => x-encoded-content-length
                )

            [protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 1.1
            [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
                (
                    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #149
                    [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 0
                    [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
                    [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )


    [_objectData:LazyJsonMapper\LazyJsonMapper:private] => Array
        (
            [users] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [pk] => xxxx
                            [username] => x
                            [full_name] => x
                            [is_private] => 
                            [profile_pic_url] => x
                            [is_verified] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [pk] => x
                            [username] => x
                            [full_name] => x
                            [is_private] => 1
                            [profile_pic_url] => x
                            [profile_pic_id] => x
                            [is_verified] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [pk] => x
                            [username] => x
                            [full_name] => x
                            [is_private] => 1
                            [profile_pic_url] => x
                            [profile_pic_id] => x
                            [is_verified] => 
                        )


                )

            [user_count] => 2
            [status] => ok
        )

)
```

Comment: I think the :private is not part of the name of the key, but it just means that key is private and you can't access it. Though I don't know why it's printing it out. How did you get this output? print_r()? My instinct is the class that produced this object should have a method which will just gives you the properties of _objectData directly.

Comment: I have this problem! Could you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$account = json_decode($account);
$account->user;
$account->user->username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get 'Unknown function "getBody"

Comment: What if you try with var_dump($response->users)?